Proof of factor theorem regarding polynomials
Division of polynomials: Let $f$ and $g$ be polynomials with $g(x)\neq 0$. Then there exist unique polynomials $q$ and $r$ such that

$r=0$ or $\deg r<\deg g$, and
$f(x)=q(x)g(x)+r(x)$.

I want to prove the following theorem:
Factor theorem: Let $f$ be a polynomial and let $a\in \mathbb{R}$. If $a$ is a root of $f$, then $f(x)=(x-a)q(x)$ for some polynomial $q$.
Proof: Since $x-a$ is not identically zero, we have by division of polynomials that there exist $q$ and $r$ such that $f(x)=(x-a)q(x)+r(x)$, where either $r(x)=0$ or $\deg r=0$. If $\deg r=0$, then $r(x)=k$ for some real $k\neq 0$. But then $f(a)=k$, which contradicts the fact that $a$ is a root of $f$. Therefore $\deg r=0$ is not possible, so $r(x)=0$, and hence $f(x)=(x-a)q(x)$, as desired.
I have noticed in some books, they do not include the condition $r=0$ in division of polynomials (they only use "$\deg r<\deg g$"). Since I could not find a proof that uses this condition, I could not confirm whether or not my proof is correctly explained. I am unsure if my reasoning on eliminating a condition is alright to do in a proof, such as eliminating $\deg r=0$ in the proof.

Is this not the standard proof?

You may want to clarify that $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x].$ That’s an important part of the statement…

Also — because it’ll inevitably be mentioned — the “solution-verification” tag requires you point out a specific part of your proof which you are concerned about. So my suggestion is you either remove the tag, or find some part of the proof you’re concerned about. Otherwise, you may get downvoted.

@JAG131 Okay, so the proof is OK so far? Why would it matter if the coefficients are integers? The tag was supposed to be "proof-verification", but it won't be updated when I edit it. I have added more info about my concerns.

@Mr.MathDoctor Yes, the proof is perfect as is.

Some books only use the condition $\deg r<\deg g$ because they define $\deg0$ as $-\infty$.
If you don't like this convention, what you've done is correct.

$\deg r=-\infty$ implies that $r=0$; so, $\deg r<1$ implies that $\deg r=0$ or $r=0$.

Please add the abstract-algebra tag
